# C# .net i need to record the output of the file.?

Tags: c#, vb.net

i have this program i need to make, where it runs a bat file. i got that far, so when i click the button it opens the bat. but 3 problems i encountered i have been trying to resolve for a few days now, the problem is that i need to get the output of the .bat and display it in a textbox, i got that, but it only displays the first and least line... then i need to run the .bat in the background. so you don't see the window. then i also need to be able to hit a second button to close it. the bat is a constant update, lets just say it reads a number then 5 seconds later adds 1 to that number and displays it again. and does this over and over till you close it. that would be a simple description of this

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users/jwoow/Desktop/Server/run.bat";
p.Start();                    
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
this.RunResults.Text = output;
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to just ask one specific question at a time.

### Stopping the process

You can end the process by calling the `CloseMainWindow`. Method on the `Process` object. Like this:

```
p.CloseMainWindow();
```

Just hook up the button event handler and call this method to end the process.

### Displaying outputted lines in a message box

The `ReadToEnd` method blocks until all lines are read. You will probably rather need a loop to read line at a time, like this:

```
StreamReader output = p.StandardOutput;
while (output.EndOfStream == false)
{
    var line = output.ReadLine();
    MessageBox.Show(line);
}
```

### Avoid showing a console window

To avoid showing a console window you will need to add this before starting the process

```
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Comment: `p.Close()` only closes the process handle. It does not stop, nicely or otherwise, the process.

Comment: it still only reads the default text, it doesn't actually display the returned information. its for a server, it displays how many users are on and different actions taken by different users when running. 
this is my code

Comment: `p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users/jwoow/Desktop/Server/run.bat";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.Start();
            StreamReader output = p.StandardOutput;
            while (output.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                string line = output.ReadToEnd();
                this.RunResults.Text = line;
            }`